# Issue with data show columns in mvc table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table

I have a table which displays the data. Now I have added the `data-show-columns="true"` for my table.

and table look likes below.
[image]

when I want to hide the Created Date column. Table header hides and content in same there. but its working fine for other columns like first name and email and all 
 [image]

Below is my table code.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="table-candidates" data-show-columns="true"
           data-sort-name="createdDate" data-toolbar="#candidate-list-table-toolbar" data-sort-order="desc" data-show-export="true" data-filter-control="false"
           data-show-multi-sort="false">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="createdDate" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="formatDate">Created Date</th>
                <th data-field="fullName" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="formatCandidateFullName">Full Name</th>
                <th data-field="phoneNumber" data-sortable="true">Phone</th>
                <th data-field="userName" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
                <th data-field="technicalOrFunctional" data-sortable="true">Technical/Functional</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Update:

when the column is in sort than only we are getting this Issue, If Full name is selected for sort than we are getting this same issue with firstname

Comment: What plugin are you using (tag your question) and show the associated scripts

Comment: add each column with `class="something"` and on selecting the `column name` in drop down, through `javascript` change the style of the column by the class. It is a simple solution